# Export datagrid data to MS Word with style

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF windows application and I want to export data-grid data to Microsoft Word with background colors. Please suggest a way to do it.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I have apply simple style with background color for header and alternative rows. For item source i have bind list of entity. I think these much information is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to use [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx) ... this is a walk-through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342218.aspx ... I guess you will be making use of the [Table interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.table.aspx) .

You will need msword at your machine and wherever your application is deployed.

Personally, if i had an option then i would export the data as CSV format and indicate the colour in one of the values.

That said, i don't really know the limitations but this should get you going .. alternatively try to find an open source lib that can help you with this. That is AFAIK there is no out of the box solution by .Net